# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'photo' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Every time I post new post without image I got that error. How to do so that I can only post text or/and text with image. Thanks in advance!

My Postform

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title    = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content  = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    photo    = FileField('Image to post', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    submit = SubmitField('POST')
```

My route

```
   @app.route('/post/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def new_post():
      form = PostForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
         if form.photo.data:
            photo = save_photo(form.photo.data)
         post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, image=photo ,author=current_user)    
         db.session.add(post) 
         db.session.commit()
        ......
```

Error I got from sever when I hitted POST button 
    post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, image=photo ,author=current_user)
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'photo' referenced before assignment

Comment: I can guess that if form.photo.data wasn't True so variable photo wasn't initialized. You have to add an else statement after that to initialize the variable or just break the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `photo` is defined inside the `if` block and in case that your `if` condition is `False`, it won't be defined.

Please try:

```
photo = None # put here any default value
if form.photo.data:
    photo = save_photo(form.photo.data)
post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, image=photo ,author=current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `photo` is conditionally assigned so if `form.photo.data` is falsey then the variable `photo` won't exist but the line which tries to use it will still be executed.

You should probably move the code using the variable into the same `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

The satatement `if form.photo.data` wasn't True so the variable `photo` wasn't initialized. You have to add an `else` statement after that to initialize the `photo` variable or just break the loop.